# Android app support for multiple language

Tags: android

I  am trying to localize an Android app. I need it in English and French. There are so many things related to this on the web. I cannot discard Google's official documentation on this.

[Google recommends this.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)
-b+[+]
I have the following for string.xml
values

values-b+fr

and the following for drawable :

drawable-fr-mdpi
drawable-fr-hdpi
etc..

I am not sure but it is not working when I click on the french button in my app.

Comment: French button in your app? You mean in the languages section of system Settings?

Comment: i have a button in my app that switches language

Comment: The localization is done by specifying different resource folders for different language as you are doing. So first, try switching the phone language, and see if you app UI changes to correct resources.
Changing the language within app is possible in Android but kinda difficult with some corner cases, so depending on how you implemented your switch button, the problem may lie there.....